# printing in the main function from a recursion function

Tags: c

I have to make a program where it reads from a file and then enter a string with letter, symbols and numbers and then it have to print only the letters in reverse way, now i have to use recursive function for the letters and I must use prints in the main function not in the recursive function
for example if the file the program reads from has :

input :#$f^*t&^$q*&%Y *&^q~!$n!@n*&@g%$#J*/&^(%

output : Hello Word

NOTE : ALL that wouldn't happen to me if I haven't been asked to use print only in the main function,
and also  when there is a symbol or number it avoids the if statements and the function

*The main question is : how I can use printf in the main function and be used properly where it should print reverse way and the symbols shouldn't be shown, in the function itself those thing works btw*

here is my code :

````
int decode(char x[])
{
  
    if (!x[0])
    {
        return 1;
    }
decode(x+1);
    if ( x[0]== ' ' || x[0]== ',' ||((x[0]>='A' && x[0]<='Z') || (x[0]>='a' && x[0]<='z' ) ) )
    { // here each string i enter at makes it backward by -2 for example c-->a
        switch(x[0])
        {
        case 'A':
            x[0]='Y';
            break;
        case 'B':
            x[0]='Z';
            break;
        case 'a':
            x[0]='y';
            break;
        case 'b':
            x[0]='z';
            break;
        case ',':
            x[0]=',';
              break;
              case ' ':
              x[0]=' ';
              break;
              default:
              x[0]-=2;
              break;
        }
else 
return ;

    }```

here is the main function 
```int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    char str[1000];
    char filename[100];
    scanf("%s",filename);// here i have to enter the file name to get all the strings from another file //
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(str,1000, fp) != NULL)// the problem start here it get the strings input
    {
            decode(str);
            printf("%s",str);// and in the printf it prints everything where it should only print the letters in revrse way
        fclose(fp);
    }```
````

Comment: What is your question? By the way, welcome to stackoverflow, please do the _Tour_ in the _Help Center_.

Comment: @paladin my question is how i can make this function (it works but not 100%) only print the letters in it while using printf in the main function and not in the recursive function and print in reverse way without printing the symbols like the example i gave

Comment: @kitsune Could you explain how that input string was transformed into that output string? I don't see the characters of `Hello World` in that input string.

Comment: @Zoso i hope i understand perfectly what u asked me : in my code each alphabet letter when entered it's ascii code become minus 2 for example c become a, a becomes y... and the symbols and numbers when entered they shouldn't be shown in the when compiled now my problem is that i have to use printf in the main function and when doing so i can't make the sympols go away and keep the letters and reverse them it only works when using printf in the recrsuive function

Comment: This isn't really a program. It's a program fragment. You're asking questions about `printf` and `main` but they aren't in the code you posted, so nobody understands what you're talking about.

Comment: @raymon chen ok i will post the main function then just didn't want to because didn't want to annoy you all thought the function it self will be enough but ok :)

Comment: What you posted still doesn't compile. I think you forgot the `void decode(char* x)` at the top. That one missing line provides a huge amount of context for what follows. (Now we know that `x` is a string pointer, and `decode(x+1)` is a recursive call.)

Comment: @RaymondChen so sorry i thoguht i copied all my code but forgot the function i call it like this: int decode( char x[])

Answer (score 0):

Just create a long enough char array, initialize all members with 0 and use it as a string variable (or use `calloc`). Use `sprintf` or `sputc` within your loop to "print" into that string variable and just use one regular `printf` at the end of your program.